# How i can execute multiple queries (UPDATE) in NODE using Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to execute multiples queries in NODE using Sequelize.
I tried execute with a for, but it's didn't work.
Someone can help me?

```
exports.update = async (req, res) => {

    for (let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {

        const id = req.body[i].id;
        const permissao = req.body[i].permissao;
        const sql =
            `UPDATE tetsiste_usuarios.usuarioGraficos SET permissao = ${permissao} \n
            WHERE id = ${id} AND permissao <> ${permissao};`;
        sequelize.query(sql, { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE })
            .then(data => res.json(data))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the call the `sequelize.query` but that said... you are doing this all wrong. The idea behind using an ORM like Sequelize is that it abstracts the SQL and provides protection against things like SQL injection attacks and malormed queries, which your code is susceptible to. If I mess with the request and pass in this for `permissao` it will drop your database table `1; DROP TABLE usuarioGraficos; SELECT 1 FROM dual`. That is bad. You're also calling `res.json()` on every loop, which will also result in an error.

The proper way to do this is to use the `Model.create()` function for inserts or `Model.update()` for updates.

*loop insert with sql injection vulnerability*

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const models = require('./models'); // your model definitions

// an array to store our results
const updates = [];

// use a forEach to get each entry from the body array
for (let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
  // this ID
  const id = req.body[i].id;
  // this permission
  const permissao = req.body[i].permissao;

  // update the permission where the ID matches and the permission does not
  const update = await models.UsuarioGraficos.update({ permissao }, {
    where: {
      id,
      permissao: {
        [Sequelize.Op.ne]: permissao,
      },
    },
  });

  // add the result
  updates.push(update);
}
// send all the updates outside the loop
res.json(updates);
```